# Using Spring security 3 to authenticate against REST a user only with username

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication, spring-security

This is the deal. I have to do a single authentication using only the username of the application user, and I have to work with angular, spring and mysql. Already, I Have a REST POST service that receive an email (username) and I have to check if that user exist in user table in the database, and I have to response with this JSON structure:

```
{"response":{"loggedIn":"true"}} or {"response":{"loggedIn":"false"}}
```

I found an example using **http-basic** authentication on spring security and works fine, the issue is that approach not works for me because that approach needs and username and password, but only I need a username and check if that user is on the database.

My question is How can I do the authentication with spring security using my REST service and a single authentication with only the user name field?

this is my spring-context.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/login" security="none">
</security:http>

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_REST" />
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true"  />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="watUserDetailService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

This is My Rest controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
ILoginService loginService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody IResponse login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginForm form, BindingResult result) {
    IResponse loginReponse = null;

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        ResponseError errorReponse = new ResponseError();
        errorReponse.getError().put("key", KeyConstants.NOT_VALID_EMAIL_ERROR_KEY );
        loginReponse = errorReponse;
    } else {
        Response response = new Response();
        User loggedUser =  null;
        try {
            loggedUser = loginService.login(form.getEmail());
            if (loggedUser != null) {
                response.getResponse().put("loggedIn", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            }
            loginReponse = response;
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            response.getResponse().put("loggedIn", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
            loginReponse = response;
        }

    }
    return loginReponse;
}
```

}

thanks, for your useful help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security, you can add your custom authenticator. You'd need one that simply ignores whatever comes in the password and returns true. Then you pass an empty string as a password and that would be it.